# HTTPPost MVC 4 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am building a mvc 4 web api but when ever I try to do a post to the web api the request returns

```
"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."
```

My Request Headers

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:53393
Content-Length: 39
Content-Type: application/json
```

My Request Body

```
{
  "username":"",
  "password":""
}
```

Routes

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And the method in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public MethodResponse Authenticate(string username, string password)
{
    ConsoleServiceClient service = new ConsoleServiceClient();
    return service.Authenticate(username, password);
}
```

The URL I use

```
http://localhost:53393/api/service/authenticate
```

I am still new to this, but can't figure out why POST is not supported?

Thanks

Comment: How do you make the post request?

Comment: I build it in fiddler and click execute

Comment: Is your controller called ServiceController?

Comment: yes, normal GET requests work fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `http://localhost:53393/api/service` as your URI because you currently don't have an {action} segment in your API route.

Comment: Added the {action} to the URI template and it worked, maybe update answer to reflect this

Comment: @Armand  Either way is valid.  If you are going for a more Resource Oriented approach you would name you method Post() and your controller Authenticate and then you wouldn't need the {action} and you could drop the 'service' path segment.